# Looping through 2 different arrays to check if a value exists

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Ok well i have this array that consists of 3 arrays of objects so its looks like

```
$invoice
$invoice->foo
$invoice->foo->bars
$invoice->bars
$invoice->foobars
```

i have all the foo bars displayed in a table like

```
<?php foreach($invoice->foo->bars as $bar) { ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $bar->some_field;
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $bar->another_field;
    </td>
</tr>
```

and i have a dropdown button at that looks like

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="some_url/edit/$bar->id">edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="some_url/delete/$bar->id">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="some_url/add_foobar/$bar->id">Add foobar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Would i am currently checking to see if the bar has a foobar by doing this

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($invoice->foobars); $i++) { 
    $foobar_bars[] = $invoice->foobars[$i]->foobar_bar_id;
}
```

and inside the $invoice->foo->bars loop i check to show the button like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="some_url/edit/$bar->id">edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="some_url/delete/$bar->id">Delete</a></li>
<?php if(!in_array($bar->dd_id, $companion_bars)){ ?>
    <li><a href="some_url/add_foobar/$bar->id">Add Foobar</a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I was wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this or is their better ways to check whether the bar has a foobar

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way would be to actually have a method that tells you whether or not this is the case:

```
if ($bar->hasCompanionBar()) {
    // the condition is TRUE
}
```

That way you can defer the decision what is most efficient to later. That will allow you to create the most efficient code over the lifetime of the codebase.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should have a Method into which i pass all the **foobars** and a single **bar** at a time and not just assign all the **foobars** to an array

Comment: No what I say is that you should use domain objects instead of arrays. The domain objects know about their relation to each other while with objects you need to create that relation externally.